# How to make a React Router Link look like a Bootstrap button with styled components and react-bootstrap?

Tags: react-router, styled-components, react-bootstrap

I'm migrating my old css to styled components. I have a React Router link like this:

```
<Link className="btn btn-primary" to={`/foo`}>Foo</Link>
```

How can I achieve the same (make the Link look like a Bootstrap button) with styled components and react-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I can use the component property of the Link:

```
<Link to={`/foo`} component={Button}>Foo</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Button has an href prop to allow this.

```
<Button href={`/foo`}>Foo</Button>
```

`<Link component={Button}` was either removed from Router or was only for Native, but definitely doesn't exist in React Router 6.4.